# Multiple Buttons Not Working? Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

In actionscript 3 (flash cs6), I am trying to make multiple buttons (I am somewhat of a beginner).
I do the code right (I think), because 1 button works, but the other button (when I add it in) shows 2 error messages. 
1023: Incompatible override.
1021: Duplicate function definition.

I added a separate event listener and a separate function for both of these buttons. 
I do have `import flash.events.MouseEvent`in the beginning, and I do not know if I have to do anything with this.
Here is all my code for both buttons (note: they are on the same frame, but I split them for ease):

https://s3.postimg.io/4vt5prb6r/Help.png

[image]

Comment: Pro tip: Don't listen to other people trying to limit you in order to suit their agenda. Another tip is add code into your post. We can't test code in pictures and who has time to re-type it all? That said... **(1)** Just double check you don't have another `function reset` elsewhere in all your code. **(2)** Try renaming the function to something else like `function doReset (e:MouseEvent) : void` and give feedback on the result

Comment: @ZaneClark You got that error because you've used the same name "reset" for the button and the mouse click event handler (the function), so you have to change one of them ...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara All the people on this planet know that Flash Player platform is near-dead but we can use Flash IDE and AS3 to write AIR apps or just to learn, to play, to have fun ...

Comment: It was because of what akmozo said, the reset was the same name for an instance